# RHEL 9 server with cloned disk unable to find logical volume after boot

Tags: redhat, hard-drive, find

We have an RHEL 9 server. We cloned it's disk drive to a new disk. (dd if=/dev/olddrive of=/dev/newdrive bs=4096)

It has a couple LVM partitions (as shown on /etc/fstab on the cloned disk):
[image]

However when booting from the new disk, we got an error:
[image]

Here is what lvs reported for example:
[image]

I resolved the error by first checking what ID is present in cat /etc/lvm/devices/system.devices(which I figured is what lvm uses to find volumes after some google):
[image]

Then I did: vgimportdevices --all, which put another line for sda2 and I commented the line that was already existing there:
[image]

After reboot, the system was able to boot without an issue.

Does anyone have any idea why it required manual intervention to boot properly? There is no issue right now, I am just scratching my head trying to figure a logical explanation for what happened.